# Filter a packet marked with Iptables

Tags: linux, networking, permissions, firewall, iptables

I have a straightforward scenario where a Workstation is connected to a Gateway (simulating a FW) and that Gateway gives access to the Internet. So, just to clarify, the gateway has two interfaces, eth0 for the workstations and eth1 to access internet.j

Inside the WKS we have defined 3 users, user1 with id 999, user2 with id 998 and root with id 0. And we want to filter their traffic using iptables. So, for example, we don't want user1 to connect to the internet.

At first, I did that just by filtering the packets on the WKS:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 999 -j DROP
```

And it worked, but that way was not the one the professor wanted to do so. What he wants me to do is: mark the packages by the user in the WKS and after that, when the Gateway receives the packet, filter by the mark done before. 
To summarize: I have to mark a packet in the WKS depending on the user and filter that mark in the gateway.

I've tried tons of ways but none seems to work, the mark is not being propagated, for example:

```
On the WKS:
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 999 -j MARK --set-mark 1
On the Gateway:
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

I also tried to use CONNMARK as this:

```
On the WKS:
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 999 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 999 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
On the Gateway:
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

I also tried many other solutions but none did work to me. Can you help me, please?

PD: All the machines are Debian Containers and have default routes to where they should be, and the gateway has the forwarding IP packets activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iptables marks are never actually sent on the wire. They only exist within the local kernel's network stack (and they're a Linux-specific mechanism anyway – there is no standard IP option that could hold such marks). This applies both to packet-level marks and connmarks.

Maybe your professor is confusing iptables marks with DiffServ ([DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services), previously ToS) marks? They aren't meant for security but for prioritization (e.g. interactive vs bulk traffic), but they *are* carried in the IP header and you have ~64 different values to choose from.

Alternatively, if your systems have SELinux then you could apply *sec*marks instead. While those aren't sent directly either, it is possible to translate them to an ["CIPSO"](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_Networking#NetLabel_-_CIPSO) IP option that is specifically meant to carry security identifiers between hosts. (Don't forget to remove them again on egress, though, as some ISPs outright drop IP packets containing options.)

For IPv4 only, packets could also be flagged using the ["Evil" bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_bit), however iptables can only match it but not set it. (It might be possible to set it using nftables though.)

Finally, you could assign multiple IP addresses to the workstation and SNAT different users to their own IP addresses – the gateway would then be able to match on source IP.

Comment: Hello, I've tried DSCP "marking" and SNAT and they do work. I will present that to my professor to see if this is how he wants it. I really have to thank you and appreciate that you spend time with it.